# stringified Json sent over network cannot be correctly parsed

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, websocket

I tried to implement a websocket server, using typescript (run in nodejs).

```
ws.on('message', (msg: string) => {
        console.log("got message:" + msg);
        const m = JSON.parse(msg);
        console.log(m);
        console.log(m.a);
}
```

On the other end, I use angular's webSocket client to send the data (using web browser),

```
socket.next( JSON.stringify({a: "123", b:"456"}) )
```

The print out is

```
got message:"{\"a\":\"123\",\"b\":\"456\"}"
{"a":"123","b":"456"}
undefined
```

The parsed object does not contain member a (using m["a"] is undefined too).

However, if I just write a simple javascript,

```
    const msg = "{\"a\":\"123\",\"b\":\"456\"}"
    const m = JSON.parse(msg);
    console.log(m);
    console.log(m.a);
```

I will get the result:

```
{ a: '123', b: '456' }
123
```

Is there anything wrong with the json parse? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because somewhere you stringifying it again,

if you will `console.log(typeof m)`you will get `'string'`

```js
let x = JSON.stringify({a: "123", b:"456"})
console.log(JSON.parse(x).a)
let y = JSON.stringify(x)
console.log(JSON.parse(y).a)
```

SO use only `socket.next({a: "123", b:"456"})`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, your basically making a double string.
You don't really need to stringify the Angular WebSocket.

```js
const msg = JSON.stringify('{"a":"123","b":"456"}');
let m = JSON.parse(msg);
console.log(msg);
console.log(m);
console.log(m.a);
    
m = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(msg));
console.log(m);
console.log(m.a);
```